# Why am I getting errors in apt after I deleted and then re-created `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, and `/var/log`?

Tags: apt, log, rm, tmp, mkdir

Why am I getting an error after running the following commands?

```
sudo rm -r /tmp
sudo rm -r /var/tmp
sudo rm -r /var/log

sudo mkdir /tmp
sudo mkdir /var/tmp
sudo mkdir /var/log
sudo apt update
```

Error message:

```
Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.RFX4BR for passing config to apt-key
Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.GuJXFx for passing config to apt-key
(truncated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/tmp/` needs to be

```
drwxrwxrwt  20 root     root      4096 jun  5 21:03 tmp
```

`/var/tmp` and `/var/log` need to be:

```
drwxrwxr-x 13 root syslog   4096 jun  4 00:00 log
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root     4096 jun  5 04:09 tmp
```

Please adjust those to the above using `sudo chmod 1777` and `sudo chown root:root` for the two `tmp`'s and `sudo chown root:syslog` for "log".  And check if it then matches what it liste here using `ls /` and `ls /var/`.